# My map draws a normal polyline along my route, but then draws another in a straight line

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios, polyline, google-directions-api

my app successfully gets a JSON from the Google Directions API and I scan it, create a path of coordinates, and make a succesful polyline of the route on the map. However, it almost always draws a second polyline that goes from the starting point to the ending point in a straight line (as if you flew in a plane directly from your start point to your end point)

I would like for it to not draw the straight line!

```
if let directions = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary
            {
                //print("JSON result: \(directions)")
                if let routes = directions["routes"] as? NSArray
                {
                    if let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs") as? NSArray
                    {
                        if let steps = legs.value(forKey: "steps") as? NSArray
                        {
                            if steps.count != 0
                            {
                                if let firstStep = steps.object(at: 0) as? NSArray
                                {
                                    if firstStep.count != 0
                                    {
                                        if let paths = firstStep.object(at: 0) as? NSArray
                                        {
                                            if paths.count > 0
                                            {
                                                for i in 0 ..< paths.count
                                                {
                                                    if let polyline = (paths[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "polyline") as? NSDictionary {
                                                        if let points = polyline.value(forKey: "points") as? String {
                                                            let gmsPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points)
                                                            for index in 0 ..< gmsPath!.count() {
                                                                let coordinate = gmsPath!.coordinate(at: index)
                                                                self.path.add(coordinate)
                                                                //print("coordinate \(index): \(coordinate)")
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        blah = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        blah.strokeWidth = 10.0
        addPoly(polyline: blah)
        blah.map = mapView
```

Sorry for ugly looking code. Can anyone see why/where my code makes a straight polyline get drawn? Thanks!

EDIT: After logging all coordinates:

First few entries:
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.272760000000005, longitude: -81.602230000000006)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.311060000000005, longitude: -81.619120000000009)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.311140000000002, longitude: -81.619060000000005)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.311400000000006, longitude: -81.618890000000007)

Last Few Entires:
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.274280000000005, longitude: -81.561430000000001)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.273980000000002, longitude: -81.561780000000013)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.273860000000006, longitude: -81.56195000000001)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.273860000000006, longitude: -81.56195000000001)

Comment: This is the kind of effect you would get if your first and last points are the same.  Or if your drawing a final line segment from last point back to first point.  Have you confirmed that it really is drawing a second polyline, or is it really all part of the one polyline?  If you log out all the coordinates, is the first coordinate the same as the last coordinate?  Can you show us the log output listing all the coordinates?  Also, add some logging (or use some breakpoints) to see how many paths really are drawn.

Comment: its funny you say that because yes, I am trying to generate circular routes where the last segment goes from a randomly generated point back to the initial start. However, I had this problem even when I was simply getting instructions from point A to point B; I have a button that when pressed, generates routes. But the first click of the button never does anything, even though the json file still prints the Json i get. The routes are always drawn on the second press (no idea why)

Comment: i will get a log of the points in one moment!

Comment: the log is most certainly too long to post in a comment... Where could I put it?

Comment: anywhere that you can link to.  Or how about posting the first few and last few lines (to the question, rather than to a comment)

Comment: Good idea, added them!